# sed - extract specific characters from a string

Tags: linux, command-line, awk, sed, tr

So I have some unclean HTML:

```
"<table class="content divbackground"><tr><td class='title'>&nbsp;</td><td class='title'>From</td><td class='title'>To</td></tr><tr><td class='entry'>Monday</td><td class='entry'>09:00</td><td class='entry'>18:00</td></tr><tr><td class='entry'>Tuesday</td><td class='entry'>09:00</td><td class='entry'>18:00</td></tr><tr><td class='entry'>Wednesday</td><td class='entry'>09:00</td><td class='entry'>18:00</td></tr><tr><td class='entry'>Thursday</td><td class='entry'>09:00</td><td class='entry'>20:00</td></tr><tr><td class='entry'>Friday</td><td class='entry'>09:00</td><td class='entry'>20:00</td></tr><tr><td class='entry'>Saturday</td><td class='entry'>09:00</td><td class='entry'>18:00</td></tr><tr><td class='entry'>Sunday</td><td class='entry'>11:00</td><td class='entry'>18:00</td></tr></table></td></td>"
```

It's the opening hours of a pharmacy (the information is published on a public register).

Now I could parse the HTML using a parser, but I find that this is not robust to errors and I still have to pull out the code between `<table>` and `</table>`.

Is there some nice unix command (sed?) that searches for all occurances of:

XX:XX

inside `<td></td>` tags

where X must be a number?

Comment: What do you mean with *unclean* html? (Please review your question, state clearly what are you trying to, what have you tried what problems occurred)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

handle html with regex is not the good practice. however if your input format is fixed, you can try this grep line:

```
 grep -oP '<td[^>]*>\K\d\d:\d\d' input
```

with your example input, it outputs:

```
09:00
18:00
09:00
18:00
09:00
18:00
09:00
20:00
09:00
20:00
09:00
18:00
11:00
18:00
```

Comment: DOM against REGEX, Good agains Ev(i|a)l! :) hihi! Let's wait until the OP describes his problem more clearly...

Comment: Wow. I love this stuff. Regex so powerful. Working perfectly!

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. You've saved me so much time. I don't fully understand your regex (especially the bit after the td and the \K), but it's very lightweight and looks robust.

Comment: @Eamorr It might work in the first place. But note that it would also match `<td>00:00` following `<foobar>` or whatever..

Comment: @Eamorr `\K` is very similar as look behind, but it supports dynamic length. that's it.  BTW, @hek2mgl is right, regex should not be chosen as tool to handle xml/html in serious work. It is only suitable for some dirty and quick requirements. You should know the risk.

Comment: @Kent You are right. You might use a lookahead assertion to ensure that the `</td>` will follow the time-string. Also you might mention that it is possible with GNU grep only. (And a good reason to use GNU tools)